# Sun javac doesn't compile generated sources, while OpenJDK one does?

Tags: java, hibernate, code-generation, javac

I am using JPA entities, and hibernate-jpamodelgen to generate sources for classes like `EntityName_.java`.

Strange thing is, when I run javac from Sun JDK (1.6.0_24) sources for `EntityName_` are created, but not compiled.

When I run OpenJDK one (1.6.0_22), it is generated and also compiled. I can find `EntityName_.class` files in output directory.

Why the difference? And can I somehow force Sun javac to not only generate source, but also compile all the generated files?

Comment: Is there an error message? Probably it is using OpenJDK specific classes.

Comment: No error messages. Messages from both compilers are exactly the same.

Comment: So how do you know it doesn't compile?

Comment: Can you compile generated files manually?

Comment: @OscarRys I know, because when I run Sun, I can't find EntityName_.class in output folder. @Nikita Yes, I can compile it.

Comment: when you compile run javac with -Xlint argument to enable all warnings

Comment: Must be something to do with build environment. How are you calling javac? Do you use ant or other build tool?